# How to fix "open failed: errno 13" exception in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am developing a camera app using CrossMedia.Plugin , when I take a photo using phone camera or from my phone gallery ,the app crashes and the output window shows open failed: errno 13 exception.How to fix it...

Please Help me.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="27" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application android:label="Sample.App.Android">

<provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" 
 android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
 android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">

<meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" 
android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
</provider>

</application>
```

Granting permissions

```
public async void Permissions()
    {
        try
        {
            var status = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Storage);

            if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
            {
                if (await CrossPermissions.Current.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationaleAsync(Permission.Storage))
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Need location", "Gunna need that location", "OK");
                }

                var results = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(Permission.Storage);
                //Best practice to always check that the key exists
                if (results.ContainsKey(Permission.Storage))
                    status = results[Permission.Storage];
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

MainActivity.cs

```
public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] 
  permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
    {

 PermissionsImplementation.Current.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, 
    permissions, grantResults);
        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, 
    grantResults);
    }
```

Code for take image

```
   takePhoto.Clicked += async (sender, args) =>  
        {  

            if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)  
            {  
                await DisplayAlert("No Camera", ":( No camera avaialble.", "OK");  
                return;  
            } 

            /*After the below code app crashes*/

            var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions  
            {  
                PhotoSize = Plugin.Media.Abstractions.PhotoSize.Medium,  
                Directory = "Sample",  
                Name = "test.jpg"  
            });  

            if (file == null)  
                return;  

            await DisplayAlert("File Location", file.Path, "OK");  

            image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>  
            {  
                var stream = file.GetStream();  
                file.Dispose();  
                return stream;  
            });  
        };
```

output window

```
 01-31 16:12:15.896 W/Adreno-ES20(25406): <get_gpu_clk:229>: open failed: 
 errno 13
 01-31 16:12:16.111 W/View    (25406): requestLayout() improperly called by 
 md51558244f76c53b6aeda52c8a337f2c37.ScrollViewContainer{77582fd V.E...... 
 ......ID 0,0-720,1280} during layout: running second layout pass
 01-31 16:12:16.154 W/OpenGLRenderer(25406): Bitmap too large to be uploaded 
 into a texture (2476x4416, max=4096x4096)
 01-31 16:12:16.200 W/OpenGLRenderer(25406): Bitmap too large to be uploaded 
 into a texture (2476x4416, max=4096x4096)
 01-31 16:12:17.440 W/OpenGLRenderer(25406): Bitmap too large to be uploaded 
 into a texture (2476x4416, max=4096x4096)
 01-31 16:12:17.458 W/OpenGLRenderer(25406): Bitmap too large to be uploaded 
 into a texture (2476x4416, max=4096x4096)
 The thread 0x5 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
 Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #4
 The thread 0x4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
 Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #7
 The thread 0x7 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
 Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #3
 Thread started: <Thread Pool> #8
 The thread 0x3 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
 Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #6
 Thread started: <Thread Pool> #9
 Thread started: <Thread Pool> #10
 The thread 0x6 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: Have you checked for permissions runtime?

Comment: Yes, I updated  my code

Comment: @Lakshya Error 13 is a file-based permission error.

Comment: @SushiHangover Is there any solution...

Comment: @Lakshya Where in the code is the error coming from. Full exception/stacktrace...

Comment: @SushiHangover I posted my output window

Comment: @Lakshya Please add the relevant output window into the question as text so we can look through it

Comment: @G.hakim  ok, am updated

Comment: Oh i see it now the problem is with the Image, i will update my answer soon

Answer (score 0):

`Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture` exception is usually thrown when the image bitmap is too big to load in a small view. Now, android uses bitmaps that resizes the image based on the display resolution and density.

Now since you are using Xamarin.Forms this(Bitmap) is not directly available to you as it is a native class.

What you can do here is write your own BitmapFactory to resize this image as per your view or you can use existing NuGet packages for this:

I suggest you use the [FFImageLoading](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading) package by Daniel luberda, it is a marvellous plugin well maintained and widely accepted by the Xamarin Community

You can use it just like you use the Image control as shown below:

```
<ffimageloading:CachedImage WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="100"
        DownsampleToViewSize="true"
        Source = "{Binding MyImage}" />
```

Now there are a bunch of downsampling API's provided by FFImage and can be found on their [GitHub](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/wiki/Xamarin.Forms-API).

**UPDATE**

- The `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` & `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions are required, but the library will automatically add this for you. Additionally, if your users are running Marshmallow the Plugin will automatically prompt them for runtime permissions. You must add the Permission Plugin code to your Main or Base Activities:

  ```
    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
     {           
       Plugin.Permissions.PermissionsImplementation.Current.
       OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);`
     }
  ```
- This plugin uses the [Current Activity Plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/CurrentActivityPlugin/blob/master/README.md) to get access to the current Android Activity. Be sure to complete the full setup if a MainApplication.cs file was not automatically added to your application. Please fully read through the Current Activity Plugin Documentation. At an absolute minimum you must set the following in your Activity's OnCreate method:

  ```
   CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, bundle);
  ```

  It is highly recommended that you use a custom Application that is outlined in the Current Activity Plugin Documentation
- Android Misc Setup
  By adding these permissions Google Play will automatically filter out devices without specific hardware. You can get around this by adding the following to your AssemblyInfo.cs file in your Android project:

  ```
  [assembly: UsesFeature("android.hardware.camera", Required = false)]
  [assembly: UsesFeature("android.hardware.camera.autofocus", Required = false)]
  ```
- Android File Provider Setup
  You must also add a few additional configuration files to adhere to the new strict mode:

  Add the following to your AndroidManifest.xml inside the  tags:

  ```
   <provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" 
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider" 
    android:exported="false" 
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">

   <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" 
               android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
   </provider>
  ```

  Add a new folder called xml into your Resources folder and add a new XML file called file_paths.xml. Make sure that this XML file has a Build Action of: AndroidResource.

  ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <external-files-path name="my_images" path="Pictures" />
   <external-files-path name="my_movies" path="Movies" />
   </paths>
  ```
- You can read more at: https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

Goodluck!

Revert in case of queries

Comment: ok , actually the app crashes before assigning the path to image.And am also tried with out adding the code image.Source=" " but my app crashes after selecting or taking the image.

Comment: Its because of the dispose i guess can you remove that and check?  remove `file.Dispose();`

Comment: Same error, app crashes before the path assign to the image.sourse=" " or after selecting the image.

Comment: var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions  
            {  
                PhotoSize = Plugin.Media.Abstractions.PhotoSize.Medium,  
                Directory = "Sample",  
                Name = "test.jpg"  
            });   after this line app crashes , and but the project is still in the running state

Comment: `!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported` this statement of yours is broken, my friend! What it does is as below: If the camera is not available or take a photo is not supported go in the if statement. The OR should be an AND here

Comment: I refer this link to implement this functionality:-https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin

Comment: can you not use this `PhotoSize = Plugin.Media.Abstractions.PhotoSize.Medium` and see what happens?

Comment: I tried with that also, but still app crashes.But the same code working in other projects.I don't know why this happens in this project only

Comment: are you sure you have all the required NuGets and you have initialized  everything properly?

Comment: Yes,I am using the Xam.Plugin.Media package and add the permissions in manifest file and also grant the permission in main activity

Comment: I just found the issue on Button click start you should have this `await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();` check [here](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin#usage)

Comment: Try deleting the app and then running again, sometimes the xamarin doesn't build properly

Comment: I already tried with uninstalling ,and also delete the bin and obj folders

Comment: Do you have the CurrentActivityPlugin in your app? I am updating things that i think are possible reasons for your issue

Comment: Yes, I added this code in MainActivity. :-  CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

Comment: There is more i have added! Please check let me know if something works for you

Comment: Currently I found an issue, When open the folder or camera the page automatically invoke the OnDisappearing(); method, in other projects that doesn't happens

Comment: Well that is something that will happen and should happen you cannot do anything about it.